# argument in spiders __init__ with spider crawler

Tags: python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy, scrapyd

I'm trying to use a spider crawler code to get some real estate data. But it keeps giving me this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1301, in _inlineCallbacks
>       result = g.send(result)
>
> File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
>       six.reraise(*exc_info)
>
> File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 71, in crawl
>       self.spider = self._create_spider(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 94, in _create_spider
>       return self.spidercls.from_crawler(self, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/crawl.py", line 96, in from_crawler
>       spider = super(CrawlSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiders/**init**.py", line 50, in from_crawler
>       spider = cls(*args, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Here is the code of defining the crawler:

```
class RealestateSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):

    ###Real estate web crawler
    name = 'buyrentsold'
    allowed_domains = ['realestate.com.au']

    def __init__(self, command, search):
        search = re.sub(r'\s+', '+', re.sub(',+', '%2c', search)).lower()
        url = '/{0}/in-{{0}}{{{{0}}}}/list-{{{{1}}}}'.format(command)
        start_url = 'http://www.{0}{1}'
        start_url = start_url.format(
                self.allowed_domains[0], url.format(search)
        )
        self.start_urls = [start_url.format('', 1)]
        extractor = scrapy.linkextractors.sgml.SgmlLinkExtractor(
                allow=url.format(re.escape(search)).format('.*', '')
        )
        rule = scrapy.spiders.Rule(
                extractor, callback='parse_items', follow=True
        )
        self.rules = [rule]
        super(RealestateSpider, self).__init__()

    def parse_items(self, response):
        ###Parse a page of real estate listings
        hxs = scrapy.selector.HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for i in hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "listingInfo")]'):
            item = RealestateItem()
            path = 'div[contains(@class, "propertyStats")]//text()'
            item['price'] = i.select(path).extract()
            vcard = i.select('div[contains(@class, "vcard")]//a')
            item['address'] = vcard.select('text()').extract()
            url = vcard.select('@href').extract()
            if len(url) == 1:
                item['url'] = 'http://www.{0}{1}'.format(
                        self.allowed_domains[0], url[0]
                )
            features = i.select('dl')
            for field in ('bed', 'bath', 'car'):
                path = '(@class, "rui-icon-{0}")'.format(field)
                path = 'dt[contains{0}]'.format(path)
                path = '{0}/following-sibling::dd[1]'.format(path)
                path = '{0}/text()'.format(path)
                item[field] = features.select(path).extract() or 0
            yield item
```

Here is when the erorr came up:

```
crawler = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess(scrapy.conf.settings)
sp=RealestateSpider(command, search)
crawler.crawl(sp)
crawler.start()
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`crawler.crawl()` method requires spider **class** as an argument, where's in your code a spider object is provided.

There are several ways of doing this right, but the most straight-forward way  would be simply to extend the spider class:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    command = None
    search = None

    def __init__(self):
        # do something with self.command and self.search
        super(RealestateSpider, self).__init__()
```

And then:

```
crawler = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess(scrapy.conf.settings)
class MySpider(RealestateSpider):
    command = 'foo'
    search = 'bar'
crawler.crawl(MySpider)
crawler.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this exact problem and the above solution was too difficult for me.
But I sidestepped the issue by passing the arguments as a class attribute:

```
process = CrawlerProcess()
sp = MySpider
sp.storage = reference_to_datastorage
process.crawl(sp)
process.start()
```

Hopefully that would be a potential solution to your issue.